# Storing PHP token in session but it keep changing automatically

Tags: php, forms, session

I have a form and I want it to be as secure as possible. So I have this function that generates a Form Token.

```
     function generateFormToken($form) {

       // generate a token from an unique value
        $token = hash('sha256', uniqid(microtime()));  
        // Write the generated token to the session variable to check it against the hidden field when the form is sent
        $_SESSION[$form.'_token'] = (string)$token; 

        return $token;
     }
```

Here is how it is activated:

```
       if (empty($_POST)){
           $newToken = generateFormToken('form1');
       }
```

Here is the function I use to check it:

```
 function verifyFormToken($form) {

    // check if a session is started and a token is transmitted, if not return an error
    if(!isset($_SESSION[$form.'_token'])) { 
        return false;
    }

    // check if the form is sent with token in it
    if(!isset($_POST['token'])) {
        return false;
    }

    // compare the tokens against each other if they are still the same
    if ($_SESSION[$form.'_token'] !== $_POST['token']) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
   }
```

My HTML form has a hidden input in which I put the new token variable. The form is sending to the same page via `form action="#"`.

The problem that I have is that for some reason, when the page refresh, even though the function is not calling again, the token changes in the session but it stays the same in the form.

I'm really lost since I thought that asking PHP to store a string in a session it wouldn't change when the page refreshed under these conditions, but it keeps giving me a different response. I tried to call `die()` before when it enters the function to make sure that the function was not somehow loading again farther in the script, but nothing happens. It should in theory not refresh.

Help me please.

Here is the HTML Form:

```
    <form action="#" method="POST" id="form1">
        <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname">
        <input type="hidden"name="token" value="<?= $newToken; ?>">
    </form>
```

And here is the validation logic that I use at the top of my page:

```
    $msg = "";
    //If the form has been filled
    if (!empty($_POST)){
       //If the form has been sent from our website
       if (verifyFormToken('form1') == true){
           //TODO CAPTCHA
           if (1 == 1){
              //Everything's fine
           }
           else{
             $msg = 'Veuillez cocher la case «Je ne suis pas un robot».';
           }
        }
    //Else, user tried to send data with his own script (Possible XSS attack)
    else{
        $msg = 'Veuillez utiliser le formulaire directement sur notre site Web afin d\'appliquer sur l\'offre d\'emploi';
    }
}
else{
    //If form is not sent, we generate a new token and store it in the user's session
    $newToken = generateFormToken('form1');
}
if (!empty($msg)){
    echo $msg;
}
```

Comment: You're sure that the function is not running again?  Have you tried `print_r($_POST)` to make sure it is empty.  Try putting an `echo` statement inside of the function to see if it is getting hit every refresh.

Comment: 100% sure..., I tried exactly this and it hasn't echoed anything

Comment: your hidden attribute doesn't hold a name attribute and make sure that short tags are enabled on your server

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, which most likely will.

Comment: Sorry, in my real code it has a name, the hidden field in the POST has the right token in it, it's the session that changes automatically

Comment: Are you checking if the session doesn't exist and then starting it if it doesn't? `if(session_id() == '' || !isset($_SESSION)) {
    // session isn't started
    session_start();
}`

Comment: if it isn't your "actual" code that you posted, then I for one, don't like guessing. as stated also, make sure you started the session. Too many unknowns.

Comment: it is almost the same I just changed the name attributes and ID for confidentiallity

Comment: Anyways form POST is not the point, it's the session

Comment: What is the `if` statement that leads to the `else` for the token to get created?  What is being checked?

Comment: It checks if the POST is empty (therefore, the user hasn't used the form yet.)

Comment: So are you sure the session variable is changing, or is your verification failing somewhere?

Comment: Can you post your actual form, looks like you are missing some name attributes.

Comment: I'm sure, it changes everytime I refresh but when I add an "echo" on my function that create the token, it does it well and the validation seems perfect I tested alot before posting it

Comment: Refresh vs Submit .... there is a difference.

Comment: @BrandonShega [they said it does...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402879/storing-php-token-in-session-but-it-keep-changing-automatically#comment48893710_30402879).

Comment: you said your "real" and "actual" code contains the name attribute for it. Well, this tells me that there risk's in having other parts of your code that may not be what they should be, and I for one can't test this; not without knowing what I am really dealing with. You'll need to debug your code as I've given you a few comments about that already in the beginning. Good luck.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you very much for that but I can assure you that the rest of the code is not the problem it... I have the feeling it could be because the functions init in the same document but I feel it wouldn't make any sense... my code is extremely similar to this it's just that the form is very long. The form is working well, it's really just what's inside the session that is constently changing..

Comment: So you are submitting the form and the session is changing or just refreshing the page?

Comment: you've a new answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30403220/

Comment: @BrandonShega when you submit sorry, I say refresh since I sometime use F5 to resend the form and test the change without fulling it again but it's really when the user is submitting

Comment: something I just noticed and that isn't consistent is this `$newToken = generateFormToken('form1');` and `$newToken = generateFormToken('form');` could be the fault here. One has a `1` while the other doesn't. Edit: you've edited that. Ok, well I can't help anymore. Too many changes and not full code.

Comment: Ya, one problem here is that it's just a bunch of bits and pieces with no actual full code, it would help to see it as a whole but that's just my opinion. P.S how do we move this to a chat?

Comment: @BrandonShega I could probably try to show you more I guess but as I said it's all in french and very long HTML, all the PHP is there and the header is sending the right value, it,s really just the value in the session that is changing and I couldn't say why.. I just tried to remove the session part from the function and do it at the same place I create the token and it still changes...

Comment: je n'ai aucun probleme a lire le francais ;-)

Comment: or setup a pastebin file with your full code then, and include the link for it.

Comment: So if you put `echo $_SESSION[$form.'_token']` in the verification you can visually see it changing every submit?

Comment: Exactly, and I see that the hidden field remain the same and the $newToken is not being defined a second time...

Comment: last ditch effort and as I said from the start about short open tags. This `<?= $newToken; ?>` the `<?=` is short open tag syntax equivalent to doing `<?php echo`. If short tags aren't enabled on your server, then change that to `<?php echo $newToken; ?>` unless I'm just blowing bubbles here and that your form's ok all along. You didn't tell me if short tags are on, hence this last comment. Bonne chance Yann, j'ai essayé.

Comment: Place this `echo session_id();` under your `session_start()`, see if it's the same every submit.

Comment: No idea then, not without actually sitting down and running the code myself, maybe something in your php.ini is messed up or the server/hosting company is not storing the session correctly, I don't know, sorry.

Comment: Thank for your help I think I'm getting very close something weird's going on with the session ill keep you guys updated as soon as I find why

Comment: then do a `session_destroy();` somewhere and restart the session if that's the case.

Comment: Do you guys think that the uniqid function would bring into the session something else then a string? And that it would try to remain unique everytime? (it's a long shot lol i'm not sure it could happens?)

Comment: But it doesn't matter, if that function isn't getting called every time then the variable shouldn't change.

Comment: I know it's my tought also hmm....

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when a `$_SESSION` token is changing even though you set it properly, it is because you haven't set `session_start()` properly.

Try looking at the beginning of the file and add a `session_start()` there if you haven't already

Comment: 9.9 times out of 10, OP comes back and says it was started. But... you may be right, you may be right.

Comment: see what I told ya? ^

Comment: but does it also set a cookie? Otherwise it might be lost

Comment: @Fred-ii- ...and I thought this OP was going to be the .1

Comment: @Crackertastic Yeah, statistics don't work like they used to. There's always that *"je ne sais quoi"* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The following has been tested.

Apache version: 2.2.29, PHP version: 5.4.24, MySQL version: 5.5.42-37.1, Architecture: x86_64, Operating system: linux

**form.php**

```
<?php
include('so-sessions.php');

$form = "form1"; // set form id

// check if form has been submitted
IF (isset($_POST['token'])) {

    $msg = ""; // default response

    // Validate Token
    IF (VerifyFormToken($form)) {

        $msg = "Token is valid";

    }ELSE{

        $msg = "Token is invalid";

    }

    echo("<p>".$msg."</p>");

}ELSE{
    // form not submitted

    $token = Set_TokenSession($form); // Set token

    // debugging
    echo("<p>Token: ".$token."</p>");

    // form
    echo('
    <form action="#" method="post" id="'.$form.'">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="'.$token.'">
        <label for="firstname">First Name: </label><input type="text" name="firstname" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>');

}
?>
```

**so-sessions.php**

```
<?php
Function HasSessionStarted() {

    $result = false; // default to false

    // Check if session has started
    IF ((session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) || (session_id() == '')) { 
        $result = true; 
    }

    return $result;

}

Function GenerateFormToken() {

    // Create token
    $result = hash('sha256', uniqid(microtime())); 

    return $result;

}

Function Set_TokenSession($form) {

    $new_session = HasSessionStarted(); // Check Session Status
    $token = GenerateFormToken(); // Create token

    // If the session hasn't started do so
    IF ($new_session) { session_start(); }

    // Unset any pre-set token
    Unset_TokenSession($form);

    // Set new session token
    $_SESSION[$form.'_token'] = $token;

    // End the current session and store session data
    IF ($new_session) { session_write_close(); }

    return $token;

}

Function Unset_TokenSession($form) {

    $new_session = HasSessionStarted(); // Check Session Status
    IF ($new_session) { session_start(); }

    // Unset session token
    IF (isset($_SESSION[$form.'_token'])) { unset($_SESSION[$form.'_token']); }

    // End the current session and store session data
    IF ($new_session) { session_write_close(); }

}

Function VerifyFormToken($form) {

    $result = false; // default result to fail

    $new_session = HasSessionStarted(); // Check Session Status
    IF ($new_session) { session_start(); }
    $sesstoken = $_SESSION[$form.'_token']; 
    Unset_TokenSession($form); // Unset the used token 
    IF ($new_session) { session_write_close(); }

    // debugging
    #echo("<!-- Tokens (Form/Session) : ".$_POST['token']." / ".$sesstoken." -->");

    // check if session and post token are not empty
    IF ((!empty($sesstoken)) && (!empty($_POST['token']))) { 

        // compare the tokens against each other 
        IF ($sesstoken == $_POST['token']) {
            $result = true;
        }

    }

    return $result;

}
?>
```

Comment: can you explain this so people visiting the question will know what's going on?

Comment: It doesn't work sadly same bug since I already start the session at the start of my document

Comment: @ Fred -ii- .. Better? 
@ Yann Chabot ... Are you refreshing the page or submitting the form?

Comment: you copied and pasted the complete code (both files) and ran it?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an ending semi-colon in your code: `<input type="hidden" value="<?= $newToken ?>">`. This -> `$newToken;`

Comment: Sadly as I said then token in the input is sending perfectly trough the POST headers, it's the session variable that is changing constently even tho the function is not being recalled